# How can I get http referrer in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

```
class HeaderHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(request):
        print request.META.headers["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

the code doesn't work, tell me that HeaderHandler doesn't has the attribute of META. what wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The attributes of Tornado's `request` object are documented at http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest

Headers are in `self.request.headers`, and they do not have the CGI-style `HTTP_` prefix:

```
print(self.request.headers.get("Referer"))
```